# End User Report Designer In SSRS Reporting

Tags: devexpress, rdlc

I am wondering for feature Implementation of (Report Designer at end User) by using **RDLC** reports
services in out Existing EMR application ,My requirement is that our Patients can create his/her reports template according to his desires.
I know this is already functionality in dev Express [End-User Report Designer for Window Application](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10715/winforms-reporting/end-user-report-designer-for-winforms)
Please guide me How can we achieve this In SSRS